# Why does an operation on a Child instance returns an instance of parent's type?

Tags: scala, inheritance

I think there is some flaws in my understanding of inheritance in Scala.

Why does appending an element to my own defined class `test` returns an instance of `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[String]` and not one of `test` ?

```
scala> class test extends scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[String]
defined class test
scala> var hashSet: test = new test
hashSet: test = Set()
scala> val set2 = hashSet + "1234"
set2: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[String] = Set(1234)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` method defined in `immutable.HashSet[A]` returns `immutable.HashSet[A]` as seen in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet@+(e:A):scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[A]). When you extend `HashSet` you inherit all of its public methods, as they are. `HashSet` doesn't know anything about your extending class. The only way you can get `+` to return your own type is to `override` the method, and narrow the return type to yours--and this is no trivial task.

Comment: Is that an actual, desired behaviour of inheritance in Scala? I don't know how complex it would be for the child to actually "update" the inherited methods with it's type, automatically

Comment: @Bacon Yes. The compiler isn't going to automatically change method signatures in sub-classes, nor does it know how to even construct an instance of your `test` class in this case (it only has an empty constructor).